# intersection of numpy multidimensional array

Tags: python, numpy

```
a=np.array([[[[0,0],[0,1]],[[1,1],[1,1]]], 
            [[[1,0],[1,1]],[[0,1],[1,1]]]])
```

how can I get the intersection of this array?

This is the expected output:

```
array([[[0, 0],
        [0, 1]],

        [[0, 1],
         [1, 1]]]
```

Comment: What is the definition of **intersection** in this case? By mine, you would not have `[0, 0]`

Comment: basically I'd like it to be `true` where both sub-arrays equal one, and `false` otherwise. maybe intersection is not the correct word...

Comment: this sounds rather like `np.logical_and`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For case provided you can use

```
a[0] & a[1]
```

or, alternatively:

```
np.logical_and(a[0], a[1]).astype(int)
```

In general, if length of `a` is not defined, you can use:

```
np.logical_and.reduce(a).astype(int)
```